# How to enable custom PHP laravel logging for Azure log analytics

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

We have developed a PHP application and hosted the same in Azure Webapp with Linux as the operating system.

Currently the log files are getting generated inside the wwwroot/storage/logs as shown in attached [ssh console app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhaeF.png).

We have enabled the Custom logs for the App Service from Log Analytics as shown in [log analytics screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A272X.png). (I was unable to understand whether path should be given from home or site so I added both).

When I tried to query the custom log in the Azure Log it is returning empty data. Please find the attached screenshot for reference [log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imhu0.png)

Please help me in understanding what is the mistake.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your app needs to be running in a VM to use Custom Log Analytics in that manner. Just ensure you've properly installed and configured the OMS agent according the steps documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-custom-logs.

Since you're using an App Service, there isn't Custom Log Analytics available. There is, however, [Log Analytics integration for App Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#send-logs-to-azure-monitor-preview) which is currently in preview and supports the following types:

- AppServiceHTTPLogs
- AppServiceConsoleLogs
- AppServiceAppLogs
- AppServiceFileAuditLogs
- AppServiceAuditLogs

You can also leverage this [SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-PHP) to write your custom log messages to application insights.